# Splash screen with progression bar

Tags: swift, swift3

I am working in a app I an considering making a splash screen with a uiprogression bar, taking the time the loading of the app lasts...
I am not sure how to do this.

Can anyone give me a few tips please.

PS: I am asking this because I think I cannot add a class to launchscreen... So is it possible to do this in the launchscreen? If so, how?

Comment: No, you cannot add progress bar in launch screen. Splash screen is for waiting for users until app is launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much on launchscreen since, even custom font's not are loaded on it. Just create initial navigation controller, where first view controller will have your progress bar, write a delegate for your progress bar so when it will finish loading it will do action.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything on launch screen. But If you want to show uiprogress bar on launch screen then you have to design a view controller just like your launch screen and show it right after launch screen, do your work while uiprogress bar is showing when you finish your work then show next controller.